# mysql statistics data for users - how do I get columns per date range?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have 3 tables in a query:

apiusers, users

- these contain a user id, and a name.

download_stats:

this contains usertype (1 = users, 2 = apiusers), date, file downloaded_id.

What I want to do is get a layout of:

| user id | name | download stats for january | download stats for february

etc.

I'm currently trying with this query, which takes forever:

```
SELECT name,queryuserid,count(ROWA.id) ,count(ROWB.id) 
FROM (SELECT IFNULL(u.name, au.companyname) AS name,IFNULL(u.id, au.id) AS queryuserid
    FROM apiusers as au, users as u 
    GROUP BY 2 ) AS users 
LEFT JOIN stats_download as ROWA ON ROWA.userid=queryuserid AND ROWA.date > date('2011-01-01') AND ROWA.date < date('2011-02-01') 
LEFT JOIN stats_download as ROWB ON ROWB.userid=queryuserid AND ROWB.date > date('2011-01-01') AND ROWB.date < date('2011-02-01') 
GROUP BY 2;
```

Is there a better way of going about this? The client wants supports to "group" the output statistics by year, month and day. So there could potentionally be 30+ LEFT JOIN's in there.

Comment: I think that to get this information 'row-wise' you'll need to do the big join. You can optimize your date selections using MONTH(ROWn.date) = <month #> rather than using a date range.

Comment: Im also wondering if there is a way to use a stored proc to accumulate this information in a temp table and then output it in this row-wise manner. Otherwise you'll need to use some sort of post processor (Perl, or PHP, etc) to get this display if you want to make the query easier.

Comment: First problem out-the-gate is that your inner query joining APIUsers to Users doesn't have a JOIN condition, so you are getting a Cartesian product... what is the relationship between them.  Additionally, your RowA and RowB are identical... are you intending to actually scroll the dates to simulate download stats per month (for example) ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you the basis, and runs an entire year sample.  Look at the pattern.  By doing a sum of a qualified IF() condition returning 1 or 0 you get the total count per each month.  Now, if you are looking for SIZE (such as download size), instead of 1, 0, you can just substitute the fileSize instead of 1 and you'll have the total downloaded size... put them as different columns and you can have both Count of downloads and totalSize of downloads.  Expand the date range over year, just keep going with the pattern...

```
SELECT 
      AllUsers.Name,
      AllUsers.QueryUserID,
      SUM( if( SD.Date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-31', 1, 0 )) as CountJan2011,
      SUM( if( SD.Date BETWEEN '2011-02-01' and '2011-02-28', 1, 0 )) as CountFeb2011,
      SUM( if( SD.Date BETWEEN '2011-03-01' and '2011-03-31', 1, 0 )) as CountMar2011,
      SUM( if( SD.Date BETWEEN '2011-04-01' and '2011-04-30', 1, 0 )) as CountApr2011,
      SUM( if( SD.Date BETWEEN '2011-05-01' and '2011-05-31', 1, 0 )) as CountMay2011,
      SUM( if( SD.Date BETWEEN '2011-06-01' and '2011-06-30', 1, 0 )) as CountJun2011,
      SUM( if( SD.Date BETWEEN '2011-07-01' and '2011-07-31', 1, 0 )) as CountJul2011,
      SUM( if( SD.Date BETWEEN '2011-08-01' and '2011-08-31', 1, 0 )) as CountAug2011,
      SUM( if( SD.Date BETWEEN '2011-09-01' and '2011-09-30', 1, 0 )) as CountSep2011,
      SUM( if( SD.Date BETWEEN '2011-10-01' and '2011-10-31', 1, 0 )) as CountOct2011,
      SUM( if( SD.Date BETWEEN '2011-11-01' and '2011-11-30', 1, 0 )) as CountNov2011,
      SUM( if( SD.Date BETWEEN '2011-12-01' and '2011-12-31', 1, 0 )) as CountDec2011
  FROM
      ( select distinct 
                APIUsers.CompanyName as Name,
                APIUsers.QueryUserID
           from APIUsers
        UNION
        select 
              Users.Name,
              Users.QueryUserID
           from Users ) AllUsers

      LEFT JOIN stats_download SD
          ON AllUsers.QueryUserID = SD.UserID
         AND SD.Date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' and '2011-12-31'
   GROUP BY 
      2;
```

Comment: That was quick, very quick. I'm gonna replace some other code I have elsewhere to do transpose's with that, but I'm not sure I can use it for this problem.

One of their requirements here is that they I to be able to filter users/api users in a small time range, and have everyone show up. Including the ones with 0 downloads. And since this is based on the stats_download table it wont show if there are 0 entries.

Comment: @neuron, I've updated the query to pre-query distinct Users/Names and do a LEFT JOIN for the stats.  So now, you can filter on specific people and/or date ranges.  You can put WHERE clauses in the "AllUsers" prequery, or adjust the dates too.

Comment: I'm in awe... my old query took about a minute before I ctrl+c'd it, full well knowing I wouldn't be able to use that in a production enviroment. And that's with 2 seperate months being pulled into the stats. 

Your query : 3 seconds! (and that's 12 months being pulled in..)

Comment: There are PLENTY of people who write good SQL samples, keep an eye out  for others even if its a learning experience.  You could also click on a person to see all the different questions and answers they have done/offered.  At the bottom of their "profile" area, also lists the tags they have participated... click on that, and it will narrow down their answers to only those hitting that category tag.  Some really complex ones out there.  It could really get your mind rolling to better understand structuring and relations along your learning ways...

Comment: Thank you! I'm spending more and more time on stackoverflow, but the amount of people and information can be overwhelming. The tags trick helps a lot though!

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way.

You need to do just one join with the stats_download and aggregate on months, I assume the method GETMONTH extracts the month from a date (every database has its own method, you didn't specify what you are using)

```
(
SELECT name,queryuserid,count(stats_download.id) as cnt,GETMONTH(stats_download.date) as month
FROM (SELECT IFNULL(u.name, au.companyname) AS name,IFNULL(u.id, au.id) AS queryuserid
    FROM apiusers as au, users as u 
    GROUP BY 2 ) AS users 
LEFT JOIN stats_download ON stats_download.userid=queryuserid
GROUP BY name, queryuserid, GETMONTH(stats_download.date)
) as TableA
```

so now we have a table that create columns according to the different groups, so we inner join the table with itself (should be much faster since this table is smaller)

```
Select name, queryuserid, A.cnt as January, B.cnt as February from TableA left join TableA as A on (TableA.queryuserid = A.queryuserid and A.month=1) left join TableA as B on (TableA.queryuserid = B.queryuserid and B.month=2)
```

I haven't run it so I may have some typos but this is the direction.
Hope it helps...

Comment: Reading this from the bus, so I haven't tried it either. But it looks very interesting.
I'm using mysql, so I assume I'd use insert into for the first query, for a temporary table?

Comment: well I wrote it like this so it would be easier to understand, if I were to use it I would wrap the second query around the first. That is why I used parenthesis in the first query. But that is more of a style issue.

Comment: How does that work with you using "left join" though? Wouldn't you then need to either put TableA somewhere temporary, or do the TableA query both in the "From" and all "left join" queries?

Comment: To verify you get all the user you should start with the original table and left join from there, i.e. `SELECT users.name, users.queryuserid, A.cnt, B.cnt from users left join TableA as A on (...) left join TableB as B on (...) and so on` users with no input on a particular month will get a null result